# Setting up foreign keys resulted to (errno:150 "Foreign key constraint incorrectly formed")

Tags: mysql, sql

Im having trouble setting up foreign keys, it always resulted to `(errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")`, even though the column data type and length are correct.

here is the table `test`

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `test_column_one` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `test_column_two` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`test_column_one`, `test_column_two`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4
COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

and this is the table which consist of the foreign keys

```
CREATE TABLE `test_two` (
  `test_no` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `test_one` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `test_two` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`test_no`),
  INDEX `index_one_test_column_one` (`test_one` ASC),
  INDEX `index_two_test_column_two` (`test_two` ASC)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4
COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `test_two`
    ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_test_one`
    FOREIGN KEY (`test_one`)
    REFERENCES `test` (`test_column_two`);

ALTER TABLE `test_two`
    ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_test_two`
    FOREIGN KEY (`test_two`)
    REFERENCES `test` (`test_column_two`);
```

any idea where did I get wrong? Thank you in advance

Comment: No. 3 from the most upvoted answer in the duplicate question.

Comment: But from the test table the test_column_two is already a primary key?

Comment: No, it is not a primary key.

Comment: PRIMARY KEY (`test_column_one`, `test_column_two`)

Comment: Yes, I know. This show the test_column_two **is not** a primary key. test_column_one - test_column_two **are** the primary key.

Comment: what should I need to do?

Comment: Read the 3rd point again.